# How did we arrive at this form of Markov's Inequality in this proof?

Tags: probability, computational-complexity

In the book I am reading (complexity and cryptography by Talbot and Welsh, chapter 4), there is a proposition  on  $\textbf{ZPP}$($ \textbf{ZPP} = \textbf{RP} \cap \textbf{coRP}$-[proposition $4.13$](http://cryptome.org/2013/01/aaron-swartz/Crypto-Complexity.pdf)), page 80, where I don't understand the following:

> By Markov's Inequality:
>
> we know that the probability that any random variable exceeds twice
>   its expected value is at most $\frac {1}{2}$. Thus if $x \in L$ then
>
> $$Pr[\text{M accepts $x$ in time at most 2p(n)}]  \ge \frac {1}{2}$$